# Present another View Controller

Tags: swift

```
let VC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PapersMenu")
    VC?.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
        self.present(VC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I am using the above code to present a new ViewController. I have given the storyboard ID as "PapersMenu"

what I want to do is, when a user clicks on any table cell in a table view, I want to forward the user to a ViewController which is "PapersMenu"
But the code is not working.

Comment: I am using this code inside the  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {} function

Comment: edit your question by adding all the necessary information. Don't add comments

Comment: _How_ is your code not working?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try to call `present` method in some non-UIViewController class, thus your code will not work.

```
let sb : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let VC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PapersMenu")

self.present(VC!, animated: true, completion: nil) // where self is subclass of `UIViewController`.
```

Or use another viewController

```
let rootController = (UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!!.rootViewController)!
rootController.present(VC!, animated: true, completion: nil) // when you try to call `present` method in some class, which is not subclass of `UIViewController`.
```

Comment: If it is `non-UIViewController` then it will break on the first line `storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PapersMenu")`. I think this is a wrong assumption.

Comment: Yeah it is not a nonUIViewController, neither of those are working

Comment: In my project i have table view controller (menu) and i use same way to call new view controllers. It works for me. What is your expectation?